# Is it possible to get "paths" functionality with tsify similar to what vanilla browserify has?

Tags: node.js, typescript, browserify, tsify

In vanilla browserify you can specify "paths" option to set directories where browserify looks for "required" files.

```
browserify({paths: ["./source/App"]})
```

When using tsify to compile TypeScript, this option seems to be ignored. The reason for using paths in the first place, is to avoid having every require statement start with `"../../../etc"`.

I know an alternative option is to place the code in node_modules, but firstly that does seem pretty odd (you wouldn't normally keep you application code with your dependencies) but it also requires you to commit node_modules to your repositories and make sure no one ever clears that directory to reinstall dependencies.

The other alternative; symlinks don't work on windows, and also seems like quite a "hacky" solution.

I am quite new to browserify (coming from RequireJS), so it is possible that I overlooked something. But at this point I really would appreciate some input. If it makes any difference I am also using gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that [Path mappings based module resolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039) feature is [proposed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) for TypeScript 1.8 and [tsify](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify) is a thin wrapper of the TypeScript compiler, I can't imagine a way how it can work nowadays.

I expect that TypeScript 1.8 will be ready in a few months.

Comment: That is pretty cool. Though I was hoping for solution to the problem now ;)
I also don't need anything as complex as that feature, I just need to set a single root/base dir.